# having trouble with css floating forms left and right

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/C95uc/3/

I am having trouble with my css. I want to display both drop down menus on the left above one another and I want to display the text inputs on the right hand side, but how can I do this?

Below is the html code:

```
<div class='lt-container'>
<form id='moduleForm'>
<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
<option value="">Please Select Module</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</div>




<div  class='lt-container' >
<form id='moduleExistForm'>
 <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
<option value="">Please Select Course</option>
    </select> </form> 
</div>


<div  id='rt-container' >
<form id='detailsForm'>


    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='idmodule' name='moduleid' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Module ID:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='nomodule' name='moduleno' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Module Name:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='namemodule' name='modulename' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Credits:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='credits' name='creditsname' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div id='moduleAlert'></div>

    </form>



    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.lt-container, #rt-container {
 float: left;   
 }

#rt-container {
 clear: right;
 margin-left: 5%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/C95uc/4/

```
<div class='lt-container'>
<form id='moduleForm'>
<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
<option value="">Please Select Module</option>
    </select>
    </form>

<form id='moduleExistForm'>
 <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
<option value="">Please Select Course</option>
    </select> </form> 
</div>
```

Both `<select>` go in the same `<div class='lt-container'>`

Answer (score 0):

The two dropdowns don't stack on top of each other because you have assigned both of them a "float:left" property which makes them go side by side. Instead, wrap them in a div and make that div float left.

```
<div class="lfloat">
  <!-- Both Dropdowns -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lfloat {
 float:left;
}
```

Be sure to add a "float:right" property to the form so that it doesn't appear below the two drop downs.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/C95uc/5/